# Vim: A way to flag up when there is a shorter way to perform the same command?

Tags: vim, binding, vi

I'm learning vim bindings.

Is there a feature (or a tool) that, for a given command, will flag up any optimized/shorter way to perform it, when there is one?

For instance,
if I do (while in normal mode) `i + →`, I want a warning to be triggered saying that `a` is shorter to perform the same action.

Comment: It makes no sense for me.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス, do you mean that you don't understand the question ?

Comment: I am pointing to the example.

Comment: 42. But seriously - it does not make sense to me neither. Look at vimgolf.com and try to design an oracle-like tool that solves all questions of the universe. It does not exist. If you are looking for a generic list of commands' equivalence, you will probably not find any - why bother about 'Vx' or 'dd'. Trust me, if you have gone through all basic motions/commands you can still achieve a pretty good results at vimgolf - but does it really matter in a real life?

Comment: Definition of efficiency differs from person to person. So, make no sense to me either

Comment: You just use your brain. There's no better tool.

Comment: I rephrased the question for better clarity, please see the edit.
@Meninx-メネンックス,

Comment: You still not get it.

Comment: Why are you downvoting the question ? I believe it's well phrased and understandable, so why the downvote ?

Comment: Because what you ask a) doesn't exist, b) can't exist, c) makes no sense. Learning is supposed to be *deliberate*.

Comment: You're wrong @romainl. (c) Bad habits can be corrected without pain thanks to external tools that flag them up. For instance, I had the bad habit to keep my pinkie on the ⇧ key instead of using ⇪ to type a long word in caps. I disabled the shift behavior after 3 consecutive keystrokes and painlessly learned to use caps lock.
(b) Such a tool can absolutely exist, I know how to program it. I'm sorry if you don't but it has nothing to do with me. Just intercept keystrokes, check that the user is actually using vim, use an equivalency table and trigger a popup when needed.

Comment: And downvoting should be reserved for ill-formulated questions, not questions that you disagree with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand that vim is highly customizable. It's so that is prone to do that mistakes that you mention. But, the only way to know that there is better shortcut for an operation: It's first check the vim documentation and then check your owns functions.
There is no such algorithm, plugin or function in vimscript that could enable detect that as far as I'm concerned.

You should read all chapters of [learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com), understanding how vim works as a result you should know how to handle your owns functions, mappings, etc.

Comment: I would guess that the question was not even targeting vimscript, it is rather about saving keystrokes just like in vimgolf. The problem is that vim is not an IDE, does not have a predefined set of functions with keybindings that can be used instead of a mouse and cannot be shown as a notification if done with mouse instead of keyboard. Get familiar with all modes (including variants of visual). Check carefully internal vim help, e.g. ":h operator", ":h word-motion", ":h object-motion", then use stackoverflow/vimgolf as a random source of inspiration and driving force to optimize your habits.

Comment: vimgolf worth to check.